# How can I get the freshdesk help icon in right bottom in Vue/Quasar?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, freshdesk

How can I get the freshdesk help icon in right bottom
I tried my code, no error but I cannot see the icon

My code

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/12000000025.js' async defer />
<script>
export default {
  created () {
    window.fwSettings = {
      widget_id: '12000000025',
      locale: 'en'
    }
    !(function () {
      if ('function' !==typeof window.FreshworksWidget) {
        var n = function () {
          n.q.push(arguments)
        }
        n.q = [], window.FreshworksWidget = n
      }
    })()
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

mounted() {
window.fwSettings = {
widget_id: 1232323248,
}
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
!(function () { if (typeof window.FreshworksWidget !== 'function') { var n = function () { n.q.push(arguments) }; n.q = [], window.FreshworksWidget = n } }())

```
const externalScript = document.createElement('script')
externalScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/1323232048.js')
externalScript.setAttribute('id', 'freshdesk-widget')
externalScript.setAttribute('defer', true)
externalScript.setAttribute('async', true)
document.head.appendChild(externalScript)
```

},